# Proper way to split declaration and definition of inlined non member operator (linker issue)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, inline, operator-keyword

I have a visual studio solution with 2 projects, one of which is a **static library**. 
In this library I have the following class with some overloaded operators (both members and not):

```
namespace Vec
{
    class Vec2
    {
     ...
      inline Vec2& operator +=(const Vec2& b);

    };
    inline Vec2 operator+(const Vec2&a, const Vec2&b);
}
```

The definitions in the .cpp file are the following:

```
inline Vec2& Vec2::operator +=(const Vec2& b)
    {
        this->x += b.x;
        this->y += b.y;

        return *this;
    }
inline Vec2 Vec::operator+(const Vec2& a, const Vec2& b)
    {
        return Vec2(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
    }
```

Everything compile and link correctly for the member operator. The non-member function doesn't link, the error is the following:

> Error 4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class Vec::Vec2
>   __cdecl Vec::operator+(class Vec::Vec2 const &,class Vec::Vec2 const &)" (??HVec@@YA?AVVec2@0@ABV10@0@Z) referenced in function _main

If I put the definition in the header file, or keep the definition separate from the declaration but removing **inline** keywords, it links successfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Your mistake is omitting the definition of the `inline` function from the header which declares it. If you use that function in a cpp file which doesn't contain the definition, you'll be breaking the rules of the language.

§7.1.2 / 4 (n3242 draft)

> An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used...

If you declare the function non-inline, the above rule does not apply. If you include the definition in the header, you are following the rule.

> Proper way to split declaration and definition

You can split them, but not into separate files.

```
// in header

// declarations...
class Vec2
{
    Vec2& operator +=(const Vec2& b);
};
Vec2 operator+(const Vec2&a, const Vec2&b);

// definitions...
inline Vec2& Vec2::operator +=(const Vec2& b)
{
    ...
}
inline Vec2 operator+(const Vec2& a, const Vec2& b)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: This rule also applies to the member operator, right?

Comment: Yes, it applies to all inline functions. (and member operators are member functions)

Comment: thanks for the information. It's weird the linker doesn't complain with inline function split into the cpp file for member operator, isn't it?

Comment: @Heisenbug do you use the member operator in any other cpp file?